# jquery show / hide of div on selection of related radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.imgDisp").hide();
$('[id="' + $(":radio:checked").val()+'"]').show();
    $('input[name="rdNumber"]:radio').click(function() {
     $("div.imgDisp").fadeOut('slow');
    $('[id="' + $(this).val()+'"]').fadeIn('slow');
});
});
```

this is html code

```
<div class="wrapper"> <strong><span>*</span> Number</strong>

<div class="formText">
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="100" />100
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="200" checked="checked"/>200
    <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="300" />300</div>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="rdImage" value="preExisting" />Choose from images below
<div id="100" class="imgDisp">
<div class="heading">10x10</div>
<input type="radio" name="preExistingImage" id="100" value="10x10-1"
/>
<img src="1-1.png">
<input type="radio" name="preExistingImage" id="100" value="10x10-2" />
<img src="1-2.png">
</div>
<div id="200" class="imgDisp">
<div class="heading">10x20</div>
<input type="radio" name="preExistingImage" id="200" value="10x20-1"
/>
<img src="2-1.png">
<input type="radio" name="preExistingImage" id="200" value="10x20-2" />
<img src="2-2.png">
</div>
<div id="200" class="imgDisp">
<div class="heading">20x10</div>
<input type="radio" name="preExistingImage" id="200" value="20x10-1"
/>
<img src="3-1.png">
<input type="radio" name="preExistingImage" id="200" value="20x10-2" />
<img src="3-2.png" width="20" height="10">
</div>
```

The code is working fine
on choosing 100 radio button it is showing div with id = 100 and on selecting id = 200 it is showing two divs with id = 200. 
here check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vDBDA/2/

now there are two queries
1. I use duplicate id to show similar type of divs on selection of radio button like this code

```
<div id="200" class="imgDisp">
```

though it is working fine but I know duplicate id's is a problem. how can I fix it?

1. when the page loads number 200 is checked by default.. and here in this fiddle it is displaying the divs associated with radio button 200 but in actual programming and in localhost/browser it does not show.. What could be the reason?

All your help will be golden. thanks guys in advance

Comment: Use classes over id's, `<div class="200 imgDisp">`

Comment: I didn't plan to, to be honest. Is there anything you're wondering?

Comment: Have you included the `jQuery` js script file?

Comment: @LukeDuddridge yes.. I have included js file.. the code is working when clicked on radio button, but not when the page is loaded or being refreshed

Comment: @DavidHedlund how can I call class in jquery instead of id?

Comment: @aks: `$('.200')` will yield all elements that have the class `200`

Comment: It might be added that `$('#200')` is the quickest way to select an element of the ID `200` in jQuery. It will only yield one element, though, as IDs are expected to be unique. jQuery uses the [sizzle engine](http://sizzlejs.com/) for targeting elements, and the syntax is very similar to CSS selectors.

Comment: @DavidHedlund I did what u told me.. but it is not working ;( 
See this http://jsfiddle.net/vDBDA/5/

Comment: @aks: no, you're using `$('.200"]')`, not `$('.200')`. The error `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .200"]` should have given you a clue.

Comment: @DavidHedlund now did I did it right? 
http://jsfiddle.net/vDBDA/9/

Comment: @aks: Looks correct to me. Is it working the way you want? What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

`ID` should be unique
if you want to apply some effects to some group of elements then have
all those elements in one class.
and for applying effect you need to specify using
`$('.classname').fadein();`

I have slightly edited your fiddly pls check 
http://jsfiddle.net/vDBDA/7/

Comment: whr is it working? it is showing the same result when clicked on any radio button i.e. 100 200 or 300

Comment: vignesh thanx for effort :)

Comment: this works fine... but the problem is that I showed only a section of code.. the code is very long.. still u got a VU

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `class` and remove `ID` of DOM and then use `.on()` jQuery method that allow to bind events on dynamically loaded content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class instead of ID Because ID must be unique for one html page.

Comment: I already know that.. but the problem is that I don't know how to do that in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a class to each element that you want per grouping. You may need to then iterate over those elements using an each function.

```
$(selector).each( function(){
     //hide or show...etc
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this class in your css file

```
.hide_div{
    display: none;
}
```

While hiding any div, apply this property to the div and if you want to show the div then user show_div as class. Use addClass for applying the CSS to that DIV.

```
.show_div{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    i try your code...and here is what i did...

    <div class="wrapper"> <strong><span>*</span> Number</strong>

        <div class="formText">
            <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="100" />100
            <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="200" checked="checked" />200
            <input type="radio" name="rdNumber" value="300" />300</div>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="rdImage" value="preExisting" />Choose from images below
    <div class="100 imgDisp" >
        <div class="heading">10x10</div>
        <input type="radio" name="preExistingImage" class="100" value="10x10-1"
        />
        <img src="1-1.png">
        <input type="radio" name="preExistingImage" class="100" value="10x10-2" />
        <img src="1-2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="200 imgDisp">
        <div class="heading">10x20</div>
        <input type="radio" name="preExistingImage" class="200" value="10x20-1"
        />
        <img src="2-1.png">
        <input type="radio" name="preExistingImage" class="200" value="10x20-2" />
        <img src="2-2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="200 imgDisp" >
        <div class="heading">20x10</div>
        <input type="radio" name="preExistingImage" class="200" value="20x10-1"
        />
        <img src="3-1.png">
        <input type="radio" name="preExistingImage" class="200" value="20x10-2" />
        <img src="3-2.png" width="20" height="10">
    </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".imgDisp").hide();
    $('.'+$(":radio:checked").val()).show();
    $('input[name="rdNumber"]:radio').click(function () {
        $("div.imgDisp").fadeOut('slow');
        $('.'+$(this).val()).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```